# Aligning to "North west" in moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am new to moviepy and have a question. I want to know whether it is possible to align TextClip both to north and west

```py
title_clip = TextClip(title, font="Inter-SemiBold", size=(1002, 88), method="caption", align="west", fontsize=36,
color='rgba(0,0,0,0.75)')
title_clip = title_clip.set_position((226, 803)).set_duration(duration)


detail_clip = TextClip(news, font="Rubik-Regular", size=(1469, 474), method="caption", align=("north", "west"), fontsize=34,
color='rgb(103,103,103)')
detail_clip = detail_clip.set_position((226, 226)).set_duration(duration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the moviepy and imagemagick docs, it looks like the way to specify that would be to set `align="NorthWest"`.

Example:

```
detail_clip = TextClip(news, font="Rubik-Regular", size=(1469, 474), method="caption", align="NorthWest, fontsize=34,
```

I think this would work because [align is passed to ImageMagick](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/v1.0.3/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py#L1122), and the documentation on [the -gravity option](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) in ImageMagick says that `NorthWest` can be used.